# More elegant way to program anonymous functions in jQuery.hover

Tags: jquery, coding-style, hover, anonymous-function

Let's say I have the following code:

```
$('.slide_back').hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        height = $this.height(),
        $slideHide = $this.find('.slide_hide');

    $slideHide.stop()
              .animate({marginTop: height / 2 + 'px'}, 400);
}, function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        height = $this.height(),
        $slideHide = $this.find('.slide_hide');

    $slideHide.stop()
              .animate({marginTop: height + 'px'}, 400);
});
```

You see a great deal of repetition here. Is there a more **universal** solution I could apply, rather than wrapping duplicate code into another helper function?

**UPDATE:** I am looking for some sort of 'restore state' or 'undo' function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom function which returns a new function with the desired settings. It's the neatest way to achieve that result.

Another method is using a variable to remember the current state (see method 2):

#### Method 1: Helper function

```
function universalWay(multiplier){
    return function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            height = $this.height(),
            $slideHide = $this.find('.slide_hide');

        $slideHide.stop()
            .animate({marginTop: multiplier * height + 'px'}, 400);
    };
}

$('.slide_back').hover(
       universalWay(1), 
       universalWay(0.5) // 1/2 = 0.5
);
```

#### Method 2: Using a variable

```
var multiplier = 1
function universalWay(){
    multiplier = multipler == 1 ? 0.5 : 1; //Switch between 1 and 0.5
    var $this = $(this),
        height = $this.height(),
        $slideHide = $this.find('.slide_hide');

    $slideHide.stop()
        .animate({marginTop: multiplier * height + 'px'}, 400);
}

$('.slide_back').hover(
       universalWay, 
       universalWay
);
```

Comment: Well, this function is **custom**, since it solves the particular problem. I am wondering if there is something we can use in most cases, a sort of 'undo' function.

Comment: @Lapple, I have added another method, to enable switching between two states.

Comment: yeah, this one is definitely cooler, thank you. By the way, is it possible to store `multiplier` variable as a property of `universalWay` and retrieve it as `this.multiplier`?

Comment: @Lapple You *can* store `multiplier` as a variable of the function: `universalWay.multiplier = ...`. However, you *cannot* use `this.multiplier` to get the value. For transparency, I'd stick to `var multiplier = ..`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
$( '.slide_back' ).bind( 'mouseenter mouseleave', function ( e )  {
    var height = $( this ).height(),
        marginTop = e.type === 'mouseenter' ? height / 2 : height;

    $( '.slide_hide', this ).stop().animate({
        marginTop: marginTop + 'px'
    }, 400 );
});
```